# Why am I getting slashes when inputing data into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html, encoding

If I input into mysql

```
htmlspecialchars("test'ed", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

its stored as test'ed.

If I use

```
htmlspecialchars( $_POST["txtfirstname"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

its stored as test/'d

Whats the deal with the slash when using posted data?

Comment: I believe that it's stored as `\'` instead of `/'`. Have you [disabled magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)?

Comment: Are you 10000% sure that is what gets inserted into the database? Where do you get the info from (ie. how are you querying your database)?

Comment: Rob you are correct back slash.

Comment: Are you perhaps `mysql_real_escape`ing twice when inserting? What does it look like _in_ the database?

Answer (score 5):

Turn off magic quotes, or use stripslashes. the slash is being inserted for you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: stripslashes worked. Phpmyadmin was showing test\&#039;ed for the posted data but now its showing test&#039;ed. Thanks